# How to add markers in react-google-maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Using React JS in [Meteor 1.5](https://www.meteor.com/)

**Question**: Need a way to add **Marker** using
[react-google-maps](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps)

Using ES6 and in JSX format

Followed the documentation and was able to get the map embedded in, but not able to add the marker.

Here is my code:

```
const InitialMap = withGoogleMap(props => {
  var index = this.marker.index || [];

  return(
    <GoogleMap
      ref={props.onMapLoad}
      defaultZoom={14}
      defaultCenter={{lat: 40.6944, lng:-73.9213}}
      >
        <Marker
          key={index}
          position={marker.position}
          onClick={() => props.onMarkerClick(marker)}
        />
      </GoogleMap>
  )
});

export default class MapContainer extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    this.state = {
      markers:[{
        position:{
          lat: 255.0112183,
          lng:121.52067570000001,
        }
      }]
    }
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div style={{height:"100%"}}>
        <InitialMap
          containerElement={
            <div style={{height:"100%"}}/>
          }
          mapElement={
            <div style={{height:"100%"}} />
          }
          markers={this.state.markers} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Anyone with the same problem, please follow the [demo](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/) provided by the creator.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Added the first constant

```
const GettingStartedGoogleMap = withGoogleMap(props => (
  <GoogleMap
    ref={props.onMapLoad}
    zoom={13}
    center={{ lat: 21.178574, lng: 72.814149 }}
    onClick={props.onMapClick}
  >
    {props.markers.map(marker => (
      <Marker
        {...marker}
        onRightClick={() => props.onMarkerRightClick(marker)}
      />
    ))}
  </GoogleMap>
```

Changed the containerElement size and mapElement size to pixels instead of percentage

```
  containerElement={
    <div style={{ height: `150px` }} />
  }
  mapElement={
    <div style={{ height: `150px` }} />
  }
```

And just adding marker to the function which was called

```
markers={this.state.markers}
```

Comment: You can get it to work with percentages instead of pixels like so: 
`        containerElement={
          <div style={{ height: '100vw' }} />
        }
        mapElement={
          <div style={{ height: '100vh' }} />
        }`

Answer (score 2):

I'd check over your lat, lng coordinates again. From [google explaining coordinates](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/18539?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

"Check that the first number in your latitude coordinate is between -90 and 90."

Also any other error info would be helpful getting an answer for you.

Comment: Thanks! Got the marker working as well, after I followed the demo provided by the Author. If you know about the icon size using React as well, please let me know.

Comment: And you were right about the co-ordinates, my co-ordinates were wrong.

Comment: Got the marker size up and working.
[Issue Resolved](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/pull/224)

Not to forget to add [Google Script](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map) in **<head>**